# JavaScript create and assign a prototype object to another object

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I have:

```
// prototype object
var x = {
    name: "I am x"
};

// object that will get properties of prototype object
var y = {};

// assign the prototype of y from x
y.prototype = Object.create( x );

// check
console.log( y.__proto__ );
```

Result:

[image]

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `prototype` property will be honoured only for the function objects. Otherwise it is just another property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is is not such special property as `prototype` for objects that would act like the one for functions. What you want is just `Object.create( x );`:

```
var x = {
    name: "I am x"
};

// object that will get properties of prototype object
var y = Object.create( x );

// check
console.log( y.__proto__ );

// verify prototype is x
console.log( Object.getPrototypeOf(y) === x ); // true
```